# Photoshop layers showing no effect on image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing, photoshop-cs6

I was working on a photo in Photoshop. I was trying to apply a blur on the background layer but I wasn't happy about it so I was trying, deleting, trying again etc. Suddenly I noticed that the blur effect is not reflecting anymore on the pic along with other layers e.g.- contrast, brightness etc. I even closed the picture and opened another but somehow the edits are not reflecting. I checked with the red dot button, it's on, and also checked opacity to be 100%. Can this be a bug of photoshop or some button which I pressed unknowingly, I am at a loss here. Please help me out. I use Photoshop CS6. Thanks in advance. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Is it possible the layers are simply muted? (the eye icon on the left of the layers?

Comment: No, it was the first thing I checked, the layers were not muted.

Comment: How do you apply the blur? Is the right layer selected and is that layer visible when applying the blur?

Comment: I was applying Gaussian blur from the drop-down menu called filter, while the background layer was selected. And yes layers were visible then.

Comment: Any layer that is on top that obscures the background layer completely? As in, your effect is not visible because it is applied on a layer that is fully covered by another layer?

Comment: Can you post a screen cap of your layers palette? It might help us figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

hello my first publication, you know ps as an option you can go back to more than 10 movements that you have made, example 10 painting, painting, shapes. Note that the layer you want the visible effect to apply.

Comment: Since I have closed the photo I was working on, there is no way to go back using History. Also the problem is still persisting, i.e. when I open a fresh new image, the edits are not reflecting in that also.

Comment: @KRS It sounds like you have some good points. But just as a small note in future, normally you can edit answers to include more information so two answers to the same question typically aren't necessary. Otherwise though, good show! =)